# How to make setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false) when you have scroll in gridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I have this gridview

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:numColumns="3"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="50dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

but I don't know how to make

```
setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am getting you right then you just need to add the following line in your gridview in xml

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Hop this is what you want.
Mark as up if it is. :)